# Absolutely continuity measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu ,v$ be $\sigma$ finite measures on $(X, \Sigma)$.

I need to prove there is a $\sigma$ finite measure $\lambda$ s.t $\lambda \lt\lt \mu$ and $\lambda \lt\lt v$ (absolutely continuous , that is $\mu(E) = 0$ implies $\lambda(E) =0$ , same true for $v$).

Such that for every other $\sigma$ finite measure $\theta$ that satisfy $\theta \lt\lt \mu$ and $\theta \lt\lt v$  , it holds that $\theta \lt \lt \lambda$.

So , my idea was to define $H  = \{\phi : \phi$ is a $\sigma$ finite measure and $\phi \lt \lt \mu , \phi \lt \lt v$ }

and to take $\lambda = \sum_{\phi \in H} \phi$.

The problem is that this summation might not be countable and then $\lambda$ might not be a measure.

Someone see how to overcome this? maybe there is a simpler approach?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if you also like to have $\lambda\leq \mu, \nu$,
you can define, for every $E\in\Sigma$,
$$
\lambda(E) := \inf\{\mu(A) + \nu(B):\ A,B\in\Sigma,\
A\cap B = \emptyset,\ A\cup B = E\}.
$$
It is clear that $\lambda \leq \mu$ and $\lambda\leq\nu$, so that $\lambda\ll\mu$ and $\lambda\ll\nu$. Moreover it can be proved that $\lambda$ is a ($\sigma$-finite) measure.